# In Visual Studio 2010, how can I edit the content of an aspx page with master page in design view?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, design-view

I've noticed that whenever I add a new asp.net with a master page to a project, I am unable to edit it in the design view.  I am able to see the master page content and an element that says ; however, I am unable to edit the content.  I'd like to drop things in there and adjust their properties but I am unable to access them in the design view.  How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am ignorant.  For anyone who has the same problem, be sure that your content is not wrapped inside a user control.  I did some testing and found that was the problem.